# Upgrading old thread-pool code to new concurrency classes

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, daemon

I am in the process of updating some old Java code which I haven't touched in ages. My question relates to what is the best way to do thread pools now?

Previously I used the concurrency util class's:

```
import EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.BoundedBuffer;
import EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor;
```

However I don't think that is the best way now that I am updating to Java 7.

Here is my code snippet:

```
Static PooledExecuter pooledExecuter = null;
```

....

```
private ThreadPoolExample(Int initialCapactiy, int initThreadPoolSize,
                   int maxThreadPoolSize, int minThreadPoolSize, 
                   int time) throws Exception 
{
  pooledExecuter = new PooledExecuter(new BoundedBuffer(initialCapactiy),     maxThreadPoolSize);
pooledExecuter.setMinimumPoolSize(minThreadPoolSize);
pooledExecuter.setKeepAliveTime(1000 * time);
pooledExecuter.waitWhenBlocked();
pooledExecuter.createThreads(initThreadPoolSize)

    //setup thread
 this.thread = new Thread(this);
 this.thread.setName("threadtest");
   try 
{
   this.thread.setDaemon(this)
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
}
}
```

in my run method, I also call pooledExecuter.execute(new TestClass)

Basically, I want to know which way I should be doing my thread pool now?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure how the `BoundedBuffer` comes into play but I believe you just need to say:

```
threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreadPoolSize, new ThreadFactory() {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        return thread;
    }
});
```

The `BoundedBuffer` may be replaced by the `BlockingQueue` which is created internally using a `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

If you want more fine grained control over the keep-alive settings (etc) then you can call the [`ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) directly.

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
    int maximumPoolSize,
    long keepAliveTime,
    TimeUnit unit,
    BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
    ThreadFactory threadFactory)
```

Something like:

```
threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(initialCapactiy, maxThreadPoolSize,
    time, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
    new ThreadFactory() {
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(r);
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            return thread;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `ExecutorService`, which you can construct from one of numerous convenience methods in [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), including methods to specify a bounded queue, etc, for inserting items.

I see numerous spelling mistakes in your code, for example the `Static` keyword (with capital S) is not valid and `PooledExecutor` is spelled differently. Are you sure that compiles?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Concurrency Utils. Look at the Executor framework for working with thread pools.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html
http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools

Alternatively if you are using Spring look at TaskExecutor.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

If you are running your code inside a Java EE application server, you may have to look at the server's documentation to find out the best way of using a thread pool.

Answer (score -1):

Java 7 introduced ForkJoinPool.  Article on when to use it [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2011/111004-jtip-recursion-in-java-7.html).

Comment: What is the link with the question?